# rails fields_for and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have difficulty to understand how to use fields_for and nested attributes. In order to understand it better, I created a [repo](https://github.com/nyror/nested_attributes), which is not working.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480187/fields-for-for-nested-attribute-returns-nothing), which is not helpful.

I am using:

Rails 4.0.1
Ruby 2.0.0-p247

#### Question:

1. address form shown, why can not save to database?
2. Why not work?

   `jack = Person.create(name: 'Jack')`

   `jack.address.create(street: '12w 33st')`

The main function is as below:

```
#model
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

view as below:

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
  <% if @person.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this person from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gender %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :gender %>
  </div>
  <%= fields_for :address do |address_fields|%>
    Street:
    <%= address_fields.text_field :street%>
    Zip code:
    <%= address_fields.text_field :zip_code%>
  <% end %>  
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

#### Conclusion:

1. has_one relation does not support `person.address.create`. That's only for has_many
2. rails api for `fields_for`, is really not clear. It's just missing the whole controller part. Follow it will not make it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
jack = Person.create(name: 'Jack')
jack.create_address(street: '12w 33st')
```

When there is only one associated address (`has_one :address`) you use `create_address`.  When there are many associated addresses (`has_many :addresses`) you use `addresses.create`.

Also, in your view you will want `f.fields_for` instead of `fields_for`.

I would recommend checking out the RailsCasts for Nested Model Form to learn more.

**Additional Info (to address comments below)**

Also note that `create` will make a new object and attempt to save it in the database.  `build` will just build the new object.  In your PeopleController you'll want something like this:

```
def new
  @person = Person.new
  @person.build_address
end
```

Based on your need, you can determine whether you want this `build` to occur in other actions or in callbacks in the model.  But this will get you started.

You'll also need to update the `person_params` to

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age, :gender, address_attributes: [:id, :street, :zip_code])
end
```

Comment: This is a sad inconsistency in the ActiveRecord interface.  Wish they would change it.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. 
the `create_address` part, You are right. 

However, If I changed `fields_for` to `f.fields_for`, It will not even display the **address** fields.

Comment: Can you post your "new" action from your PersonsController in your question?

Comment: Whole project is [here](https://github.com/nyror/nested_attributes)

new action`@person = Person.new` created by scaffold

Comment: You need to create the address, too: (replace ; with linebreaks)
`def new; @person = Person.new; @person.create_address; end`

Comment: @AndyV, It's so weird. Somebody need to add a patch and make it consistent.

Comment: @AWM, You Rock. That's the reason.
[guide here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) does not tell anything about it.

Move it to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: All right, Thanks @cschroed, That's indeed my problem. And also, I admitted, You're also right about the strong parameter. I did miss the permit.

Comment: Some clueless people rejected my edits so I'll put it here.  If you have a `has_many :addresses` relationship you would use `addresses.create` (note plural "addresses") instead of `address.create`.  If you're going to mod edits please have a clue as to what you're modding - the answer above includes incorrect information.

Comment: do you have any idea for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411176/fields-for-equivalent-in-android-for-rails-api-for-nested-attributes